# Debug Kotlins coroutines in Android

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to debug a coroutine in Android? When I tried to debug this code snippet:

```
runBlocking {
        try {
            async(CommonPool) {
                showLoadingIndicator()
                val a = loadData().await()
                hideLoadingIndicator()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("lala", "exception " + e.toString())
        }
}
```

`val a` has the following message: `Cannot find local variable: name = a`

In my App, I'm setting the property for coroutines debugging as followed:

```
System.setProperty("kotlinx.coroutines.debug", if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) "on" else "off")
```

Still not working. Now I have no idea how to use the debugger when working with coroutines.
May you guys help me please?

Thanks in advance

Alban

Comment: got the same problem... Anybody can help?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22296

Comment: @RomanElizarov do you think IntelliJ is going to fix this soon? Did you get any response from them?

Comment: It will be fixed.

Comment: This turns out to be a separate bug. Even more minimized case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25076

Comment: @RomanElizarov is this still not working?

Comment: @RomanElizarov, when will it be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure. The support for display of non-used variables is currently in the air. We might not support them at all, so you should be using a variable in a coroutine if you want to see their values.

Comment: Regarding `kotlinx.coroutines.debug`, it's not supported in android, see [Debug agent and Android](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-debug/)

Answer (score 0):

I tend not to add debug point at the `suspend` point as that is where `coroutine` changes the code. Instead, add a debugger at some lambda maybe inside `coroutineScope`, or inside the body of a `suspend fun`.

Also you can add `Log.d("CoroutineDebug", "your message")` in android or `println` in Java project to get some info about your code execution.

BTW mentioned, issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22296 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25076 are already closed. So you will be able to evaluate the variables easily while debugging

Answer (score -1):

I usually add a `System.err.println(a)` line, that way if I stop there, the `a` is required to be there so I can verify it's value.

Not really scalable, but for debugging it works out for me.